# how to find the current_user voted for the post? acts_as_votable rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following code in my view:

if `current_user.voted_for? post` => gives me undefined method voted_for?

How can I find the `current_user` is `voted` for the `post`?

### Routes:

```
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments, only: [:index, :new, :create]
    member do
      get "like", to: "posts#upvote" 
      get "dislike", to: "posts#downvote" 
    end
  end
```

### Controller:

```
def upvote
    @post.upvote_by current_user
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def downvote
    @post.downvote_by current_user
    redirect_to :back
  end
```

### View:

```
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <div class="vote-box">
      <p class="up">
        <% if post.voted_for? current_user %>
          <%= link_to(like_post_path(post), method: :get) do %>
            <i class="entypo-up-dir"></i>
          <% end %>
        <% else %>
          <%= link_to(dislike_post_path(post), method: :get) do %>
            <i class="entypo-up-dir upvoted"></i>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      </p>
      <p class="vote_count_text">
        <%= post.get_upvotes.size %>
      </p>
   </div>
 <% end %>
```

I tried `current_user.likes?` `, voted_up_on?` and several methods as per the gem tutorial but no luck.

Thanks

Comment: Have you included `acts_as_votable` and `acts_as_voter` in the appropriate models?

Comment: @steel Thanks for replying. I added acts_as_votable into my Post model but not acts_as_voter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like all of your missing methods are related to your User model, but not all of the methods you're trying to use exist.  First, make sure you have mixed in the acts_as_voter to your model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_voter
end
```

From the docs [here](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable#the-voter).

Second, @user.likes? is not a method.

Comment: Thanks and I added the acts_as_voter. But still it says undefined method voted_for?. What are the other methods can i check?

Comment: Hmm. Have you restarted your server, just to be sure?

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer a bit. I can't reproduce your issue, other than not using `liked?`, but I'll push my simple app up to Github for you to take a look at.

Comment: Okay, take a look at this simple, functioning app with acts_as_votable: https://github.com/adsteel/votable. Instructions to get it working are in the readme.

Comment: Thank you so much!. It's worked now. But still need to verify the downvote and everything. :-)